# Can I use underlayment to increase thickness level of engineered flooring

Tags: underlayment

I need to increase the 1/2” thickness of the engineered flooring as much I can.  Is it ok to use 1/8” underlayment.  I plan to nail not float.

Comment: Did you mean to say 1/8" underlayment?  You said increase as much as you can, but I'm not even sure what you could use that would be less than 1/4".

Comment: 1/8" is not *as much as you can*.  You can put down a variety of sub-floor products in a variety of thickness's.  Please explain in detail your plan and the desired end thickness and **why**.